# Archivo pfx a pem error opening file , no error

Tags: php, openssl

Estoy intentando pasar un arcvhio pfx a pem , al ejecutar el comando

openssl pkcs12 -in "miArchivo.pfx" -out cert.pem -nodes

obtengo este error :

Error opening input file miArchivo).pfx

miArchivo.pfx: No error

Alguien sabe a que se debe ? es confuso que dice error al abrirlo y luego no error.

Answer (score 1):

estuve haciendo pruebas e hice el archivo PKCS12 a partir de un crt y key que habia hecho hace un tiempo, te dejo los comandos para  agrupar tu clave privada y certificado a un archivo PKCS12:

Crear archivo PKCS12:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out local.pfx -inkey clavePrivada.key -in certificado.crt
```

Ahora exportar de PKCS12 a PEM:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in local.pfx -out local.pem
```

(Espero que te sea útil, si no funciona podríamos tratar de hacerlo de una manera diferente o revisar los pasos, a mi me funciona perfectamente)

Comment: Muchas gracias por responder amigo , ya lo había resuelto pero aprovecho a otra preguntarte otra duda.
Sabes como firmar mensajes SOAP  ?

Comment: Pues la verdad es que aún no se, perdón por no poder ayudarte.